# How to input continuation '...' in Matheamtica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

I am trying to compute an equation x = (a/(1+r)^1) + (a/(1+r)^2) + (a/(1+r)^3) ... (to infinity); (or to some point like ... +(a/(1+r)^10)

How to input those dots which matheamtica can understand?

Also, how can it, using same or somewhat similar technique understand the input for some simpler expression like 1+3+5+7...+113 (which should be sum of first 114/2 odd numbers)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
x = Sum[a/(1 + r)^i, {i, 1, Infinity}]

x = Sum[a/(1 + r)^i, {i, 1, 10}]

x = Sum[2*i - 1, {i, 1, 114/2}]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is rather long, and I fear there will be longer and more complex expressions which I will not be able to write formulas like this. So, is there no easy way of inputting the continuation dots? @Bill

Comment: @jawad mansoor If you don't believe you will be able to write one term then I don't think there is any hope that you will be able to write "..." and that will be enough.